# how to convert text data to an pdf file and then attatched to mail

Tags: xcode, ipad, pdf

i have some data in text format and i want to convert that data to pdf format and then attatch to mail..

i dont want to open that pdf in app...

Comment: excellent tutorial here http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/10989-pdf-creation-tutorial.html

Comment: Your question is a two-parter: "How do I create PDF from text?" and "How do I attach a file to an outgoing e-mail?" Perhaps if you edited this question to be one or the other, then posted a separate one (after searching for existing answers first), you'd get better results.